# Timezone error in php.ini on lamp

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I am trying to learn SOAP(Simple Object Access Protocol) following an example mentioned [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/) downloaded the SOAP [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) , including the file `lib/nusoap.php` which gives a warning which is

```
Warning: gettimeofday(): Invalid date.timezone value 'UTC+05:00', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in /var/www/php-practice/prac/lib/nusoap.php on line 856
```

I have tried to follow [link](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1206051) edited the `php.ini` and it does no good my region is pakistan and i do not know what to put the timezone for that i tried google which gave me

```
date.timezone ='Pakistan Time Zone (UTC+05:00)'
date.timezone ='Pakistan'
date.timezone ='UTC+05:00'
```

I tried all these in `php.ini`.But non worked for me.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php for valid timezones. I did not see Pakistan in there and they are all of type {continent/place} so you might need to pick one from there.

Comment: That helped me :)

Comment: Post it as an answer and you'll get some extra rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rinzwind

- Goto the [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)
- Find your time zone (in my case it is Asia/Karachi)
  [image]
- Open your `php.ini` ( `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
   ) and find( ctrl+f ) "Date"
- Add your timezone [image]

And you are done !

Comment: Remember to sudo systemctl restart apache2 to apply changes.